# Graphing patient data, multiple dates, multiple patients

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In Excel, is there a way to graph multiple series from one column of data?  I have lab values for patients.  Column A is date, column B is patient identifier, and column C contains all the lab values.  Without adding more columns, how can I graph lab values over time, patient by patient?

Answer (score 2):

A pivot chart might be the best solution for you to get the chart you are looking for.

> A PivotTable report is useful to summarize, analyze, explore, and
>   present summary data. A PivotChart report can help you visualize
>   PivotTable report summary data so that you can easily see comparisons,
>   patterns, and trends. Both a PivotTable report and a PivotChart report
>   enable you to make informed decisions about critical data in your
>   enterprise.

[image]

[image]

[Create or delete a PivotTable or PivotChart report](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-pivottable-or-pivotchart-report-HP010342375.aspx)

Comment: I appreciate your input.  It looks like it will work.  However, it only works for <256 patients (columns of data) - and even then is really taxing the program (or my computer, which crashed a few times since I've been playing with this).  Can you think of ways to graph out the data of >256 patients?

Comment: Performance for Excel is limited to system resources available (RAM and CPU). What you are experiencing is [Excel has it's limits](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx). The only other solution I can suggest would be to break the data up into 256 patient sets or to use a database. Both are time consuming, but with the database, you could at least import your existing data into a table to run queries against.

Comment: I dont see how you could hope to get any insight from a time series chart with 256 series on it?  Surely the result would be hopelessly muddled.

Comment: @MikeHoney Please explain your comment. You may be correct, but that is not the objective of this site. Rather than criticize the OP's approach, offer a suggestion with explanation to help the OP. The idea here is to be constructive, not just tell them they are doing it wrong.

Comment: @CharlieRB I'm just wondering what the desired output is.  You could build a Pivot Table with dates across the columns and patients in the rows, then add a sparkline chart based on a row of data for the first patient.  This can then be copied down to show a sparkline for each patient.  This can easily give you > 256 chart series.

Comment: @MikeHoney That makes sense. Why not post an answer with details how to do it in order to help the OP?

Answer (score 0):

You could build a Pivot Table with dates across the columns and patients in the rows, then add a sparkline chart based on a row of data for the first patient (Insert ribbon, Sparklines / Line button).

The sparkline has relative cell references, so it can then be copied down to show a sparkline for each patient. This can easily give you > 256 chart series.  Here's an example:

[image]